# How to scroll table view with the whole screen

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I want to scroll and display the whole `table view` in my view controller.

Like this, I want the `collection view` moves up when scrolling, and the content of the `table view` will display in the whole screen.
[image]

But what I got now is the table view scrolled just inside the table view section, and the collection view didn't move up.

This is my view controller's hierarchy, I have the `Collection View` & `Table View` inside the `Scroll View`

[image]

I have checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39916323/8078036) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38808599/8078036) but not worked.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding `collectionView` separately inside the `controller's` `view`, you can add the `collectionView` in **`tableView's headerView`**.

**1.** Create a custom `UIView` - `HeaderView`, that will contain a `UICollectionView`

[image]

```
class HeaderView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    //Add collectionView dataSource and delegate methods here
}
```

**2.** Add the above created `HeaderView` as `tableView's` `headerView` in your `controller`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Here.....
        if let headerView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HeaderView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? HeaderView {
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
        }
    }

    //add UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate methods here...
}
```

In **storyboard** - add the `tableView` in the `controller` and pin its - `top, bottom, left and right constraints` to the `controller's` `view`.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: hi but in this way I can't add collection view cell to the header view xib and add segue to `didSelectItemAt` function?

Comment: Create `collectionViewCell` in a separate xib and instead of using `segue`, you can navigate programmatically.

Comment: sorry I didn't make it clear. I want to click on different `collectionViewCell` and push to different `ViewController`. But I can't use the `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(desVC, animated: true)` in the xib file.

Answer (score 0):

You might try placing the collection view inside a cell and place the cell as the first row in your table view.